# How can I deploy production npm build of react app to Azure App Service

Tags: javascript, reactjs, azure, azure-web-app-service, create-react-app

I'm trying to deploy the npm build version of my react app to azure web service through ftp. I moved the build folder, but when I load my application's URL, the default screen loads with `Hey Node Developers!`.

I can deploy via github and kudu. However, I don't believe that's a production quality application since it's not built using `npm run build` with `create-react-app`.

I've been through this azure [guide](https://medium.com/@to_pe/deploying-create-react-app-on-microsoft-azure-c0f6686a4321), as well as various blogs. I've also included the `web.config` file. Nothing has gotten my page to load correctly.

I've tried using node versions `10.1`, `10.14`, and `LTS`. I have tried using both Linux and Windows App Services.

Comment: Welcome to SO! If that worked for you, you should mark it as the `accepted answer`.

Answer (score 6):

As Linux Azure Web Apps uses pm2 to serve a node app you need to configure **Azure Linux Web App Service** to run a startup command to serve your React app in **"Configuration** > **General settings** > **Startup Command"**:

```
pm2 serve /home/site/wwwroot/ --no-daemon
```

*Remember to change the path to your build path (The path to your index.html file).*

If you use react-router and wants to make any direct access on custom routes be handled by index.html you need to add `--spa` option on the same command.

```
pm2 serve /home/site/wwwroot/ --no-daemon --spa
```

Using `--spa` option pm2 will automatically redirect all queries to the index.html and then react router will do its magic.

You can find more information about it in pm2 documentation: https://pm2.keymetrics.io/docs/usage/pm2-doc-single-page/#serving-spa-redirect-all-to-indexhtml

I've coped with the same problem recently: [React router direct links not working on Azure Web App Linux](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/61377340/react-router-direct-links-not-working-on-azure-web-app-linux/61377913#61377913)

Comment: thanks, I spent hours trying to make it work. your post took me on the right path.

Answer (score 1):

## Azure App Services for Windows (Node JS)

### Local Git Upload to Azure App Services

1. Open up your App Service in the Azure Portal > `Deployment` > `Deployment Center` - if you already set up a deployment option, you'll have to press `Disconnect`.
2. Select `Local Git` > `App Service Build Service` > `Summary` > `Finish`
3. Select FTP/Credentials (at the upper left hand corner) > Select User Credentials - Set a password and save your credentials
4. Go back to Overview, copy git deployment URL with your git username. It should be this format: `https://<user_name>@<app_service_name>.scm.azurewebsites.net:443/<app_service_name>.git`
5. Run `npm run build` from your project folder locally on your machine
6. In `./build` run `git init` after it finishes building to initialize your git repo
7. Run `git remote add azure https://<user_name>@<app_service_name>.scm.azurewebsites.net:443/<app_service_name>.git` to add the Azure deployment as an option to push to
8. Run `git add *` and `git commit -m "${date}"` and `git push azure master:master`
9. You'll be prompted for your password. It will be the password you supplied when you were on the FTP/Credentials screen.
10. Test your website. It should be available at `https://<app_service_name.azurewebsites.net`

When you want to push updates in the future to your app service, you'll only do steps 8 through 10.

### Configure IIS for React-Router

To use `react-router` with your react SPA, you'll also need to configure the web application to re-route 404 errors to `index.html`. You can do that by adding a file in `/site/wwwroot/` called `web.config`. Place the contents below and restart your App Service from the Azure Portal.

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<configuration>
  <system.webServer>
    <rewrite>
      <rules>
        <rule name="React Routes" stopProcessing="true">
          <match url=".*" />
          <conditions logicalGrouping="MatchAll">
            <add input="{REQUEST_FILENAME}" matchType="IsFile" negate="true" />
            <add input="{REQUEST_FILENAME}" matchType="IsDirectory" negate="true" />
            <add input="{REQUEST_URI}" pattern="^/(api)" negate="true" />
          </conditions>
          <action type="Rewrite" url="/" />
        </rule>
      </rules>
    </rewrite>
  </system.webServer>
</configuration>
```